# Android ClassNotFoundException for HttpComponents

Tags: android, eclipse, classnotfoundexception, apache-httpcomponents

I am in a weird situation, which I have no idea what's going on.

The code was working, until I upgraded my Android SDK to r17.

The code is able to compile, but during runtime, `Eclipse throws ClassNotFoundException()`, under findClass method, in PathClassLoader.class

The class that not found are `"org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody" and "org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody"`

I already imported in the latest `(4.1.3) http components jar file into project-> properties-> java build path-> add external jar,`

and also clear my project N-times, yet nothing seems work.

This is from the logcat:

```
03-27 17:31:32.461: W/dalvikvm(14263): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody;)
03-27 17:31:33.802: E/dalvikvm(14263): Could not find class 'org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody', referenced from method com.milotin.core.base.MTBaseNetworkUtilities.getContentBody
03-27 17:31:33.802: W/dalvikvm(14263): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 710 (Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/StringBody;) in Lcom/milotin/core/base/MTBaseNetworkUtilities;
```

(sorry for the messy paste, is actually just 3 lines from logcat)

My TargetSDK is API10, and MinSDK is API8.

What is the reason??

Comment: Long story short, the Android SDK changed how it tracks dependencies within your project.  Please search StackOverflow for Android r17.  One of the other threads  probably answers your question.

Comment: Yes!! That is the culprit!! I used to put those .jar files outside my project, now I moved them into my project/lib folder, and problem solved. Here is where I got my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838069/jar-file-issue-with-adt-r17

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! r17 is the culprit!! I used to put those .jar files outside my project, now I moved them into my project/lib folder, and problem solved. Here is where I got my solution: [Jar-file issue with ADT r17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838069/jar-file-issue-with-adt-r17)

Thanks!