# Start a FragmentActivity from a normal Activity.. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-activity, noclassdeffounderror, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to start a `FragmentActivity` from a normal `Activity`, and I get this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in log, while the app crashes.

Should I change anything in manifest to be able to use a `FragmentActivity` in my app?

Has anyone else come across this error? How did you fix it?

Comment: happened to me. Targeting an Api level > of the Api level of the device where I tested. Do you use the compatibility library?

Comment: @blackbelt. Yes..I use compatibility lib.. app's minsdk version is 8..

Comment: Check your import. Be sure they are all coming from the compatibility library

Comment: @blackbelt Yes I added the library to lib folder and added to build path..

Comment: Check that you are importing all from   android.support.v4.app.* and not from android.app.Fragment

Comment: @userSeven7s hey, did u find a solution for this? Can u pls share??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is a stupid hint. 
But are you sure to have inserted the FragmentActivity into your Manifest file?

If so try to insert this into manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is noted here:
[FragmentActivity causing ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931040/fragmentactivity-causing-classnotfoundexception)

Please update the sdk tools. It should solve the problem.

Comment: To be more precise, this is the combination that solved the issue for me (latest software downloads on Nov 21, 2012): sdk-tools rev 21, platform-tools rev 16, support-library rev 11. I also had to add below change in the .classpath file:                             <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/android-support-v13.jar"/>
     <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>

Answer (score 0):

The `android-support-v4` library contains a bug.

So, make a new project with android version 4.2.2. Copy the file which is `android-support-v4.jar`, and paste in your project.

I solve the problem this way!