# SherlockFragmentActivity causing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-manifest

I'm having a class that extends `SherlockFragmentActivity`

When trying to run the program am getting `ClassNotFoundException`

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9967358/2310111) but to no avail.

I would also like to mention that I'm setting this class as my launcher activity in the manifest. Also when I change the `SherlockFragmentAcivity` to `SherlockActivity` I'm able to run the program but can't use fragments anymore as there's no `getSupportFragmentManager()` method in `SherlockActivity` class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Deleting the support library from `libs` folder did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the latest `adt version` (22) you need to check `Android Private Libraries`. In eclipse:

- Rigth click on project and select properties
- Click on Java Build Path
- Click on order & export tab and tick on `Android Private Libraries`

Comment: Yes I have the latest adt version. Also There is a directory named `Android Private Libraries` and it contains support library v13 jar file

Comment: then follow the steps I wrote above, clean and rebuild and it should work

Comment: I already that that option selected (ticked).. clean built the project.. Still the same. throwing me the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The wrong thing that I did is adding actionbarsherlock project to Project properties -> Java build path -> Projects. Instead I had to add actionbarsherlock to Project properties -> Android -> Library

I found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16736937/1820856

Answer (score -1):

If you are `SherlockActivity` then the method to get the fragment manager is `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: `getFragmentManager()` method is available only if i set the min-sdk level to 11. But I want the application to support atleast api level 9.

Comment: Then you need to go ahead and use the support library provided by google.
Which will work on all versions.