# FaceBook SDK Sample for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

Today, I downloaded the Facebook SDK for Android and imported to the eclipse. When I tried the FB Sample app, it informed a error :

Project 'FB Sample App' is missing required Java project: 'Facebook SDK for Android - 5fec77c'

I don't know to fix it. Who can help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just also import the library project `Facebook SDK` and mark it as `library` by going to properties of the imported project.

Then go to your example project and go to properties and add that library project.

Also Look to this **[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573581/specifying-android-project-dependencies-in-eclipse)**
"For more details you can search "Android how to add project as library project" and you will find many step-by-step blog/tutorial"