# how Do i make my TextView Font Size Change Dynamically depending upon the Parent View Size

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a Text View (without a Scroll view) Inside of a Frame Layout.

The problem is that the text view shows the Text properly till it reaches the Frame Layouts size limits.
What i wish to do is to Reduce the Size of the Fonts in the TextView whenever the FrameLayouts Size is Reached, so that the text can be viewed fully , as currently the text is cut after the Framelayouts size is reached.

Any inputs are welcome.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498762/dynamically-adding-views-to-horizontal-linearlayout-goes-out-of-the-screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to shrink the text. This has been asked many times on Stack Overflow

Here are two examples of programatically shrinking the text to fit:

http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/04/04/android-textview-with-auto-sized-content/

http://catchthecows.com/?p=72

Comment: Yes, Exactly i wish to shrink it to fit. let me have a look at the given links

Answer (score 3):

You can use `android:autoSizeTextType` in API level 26. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46798283/1162784 for more.