# "Word-wrapping" multiple buttons on Android

Tags: android, button

Given multiple buttons in a LinearLayout, etc, is it possible to set attributes such that I automagically get them to wrap over multiple lines so as to best utilise the space available, such as one might want to do for implementing a tag cloud.

I could probably use a WebView and appropriate HTML to do what I want to do, but I'd prefer to have a native Android solution.

Comment: Use `GridLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` to add buttons.

Comment: I found [this earlier question with sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961777/android-linearlayout-horizontal-with-wrapping-children) that might help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a [`GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html). This will allow you to control the excess space distribution by making the columns stretch equally across the screen.

Comment: That looks like it would do what I want, but it's Ice Cream Sandwich only, isn't it? I'm looking for something that will work on more devices.