# Buttons all squashing onto one row

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, imagebutton

I have a row of buttons and I want them to all display in a line if turned to landscape and then fit as many as it can when portrait and move other buttons to below. 
At the moment the buttons are just squashing together on one row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/Button02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/analoguebutton" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/Button03" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/analoguebutton" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/Button04" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/analoguebutton" />
```

[image: All squashed]

Comment: The following post should be helpful. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528381/android-horizontal-linearlayout-wrap-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two layouts with the same name.
Put the "vertical" one in **res/layout-port** and the "horizontal" one in **res/layout-land**.
Design the two layouts to match your tastes.
Android will automatically choose this or that layout accordingly to the device's orientation.

Answer (score 2):

Just change  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to  `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in all buttons and give `android:layout_weight="1"` to all the three buttons. Hope it works.