# How to order elements like this?

Tags: android, button, view, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to put inside a LinearLayout Horizontal some buttons, but I have the next result.

[image]

When they get to the right of the screen, they are not sorted under, they go on. I want that if the screen is small, they are ordered as follows.

[image]

Without cut any button.

Thank you. If you need my XML, tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `LinearLayout` width as match parent

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Hope it helps :)

`Update:`

Use `GridView` and set `num_coulums` to `auto_fit` and keep adding buttons as you desire,
set width & height as per your requirements

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

Comment: You can create a custom layout as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528381/android-horizontal-linearlayout-wrap-elements) or use a `GridView`

Comment: I'm trying to do with a TableLayout.

Comment: I don't think TableLayout is the way to go if you have unknown items for each row. GridView would be more apt here.

Comment: I think that your solution is the best, only one think, it need an API over 14.

Comment: Are you sure? According to [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) GridView was added in API level 1.

Comment: This is what Android Studio said me yesterday. I clicked on Resolve this, and It change my sdk api level.