# How to adjust UI for multiple screen android?

Tags: android, css, android-layout

I have a xml file as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/imagesand"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Collaboration Set Up :"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/projectname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:hint="Group Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data To Collect :"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/fnamechk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
             android:enabled="false"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:text=" First Name" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/lnamechk"
             android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
             android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last Name" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/personalemailchk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Personal Email"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/workphonechk"
             android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Work Ph." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/companychk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Company"

            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/Workemailchk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Work Email"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cellchk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MobNo." />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data Visible to User:"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/fname2"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="First Name" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/lname2"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:checked="true"
             android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last Name" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/personalemail2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
             android:checked="true"
            android:text="Personal Email"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/workphone2"
             android:textSize="13dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Work Ph." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/Comoany2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"

            android:text="Company"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/workemail2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="Work Email"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cell2"
             android:textSize="13dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mob.No" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/available"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="13dp"
            android:text="Available" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/none"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="None" />
    </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Private"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="13dp"
            android:text="Private" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Public"
              android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="13dp"
            android:text="Public" />
    </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/generate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/login"
        android:text="Generate" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

when I open this in smaller devices it looks like this. I have implemented scroll view. 
[image]

and when I open in tablet it lokks like this.

[image]

As you can see, in tab larger space is wasted, So can I utilize the free space and make the check boxes spread over the screen depending on the screen size?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `Configuration Qualifiers` for this, you can refer to the following post:

1.[Post A](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) 
 2.[Post B](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

Basically your project should look like this:

[image]

Or, you could also control the layout through dimensions, like for example:

```
<Button android:width= "@dimen/somewidth"/>
```

Declare this dimen for multiple values like this:

[image]

Comment: how to declare ems in dimen ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to put differnt images in different drawable folder based on your devices.
and the margin and padding is not directly in xml file but this is declared in dimens.xml file and then you use it..this dimens.xml file is different based on device specific...please check it.and if any doubt then tell me.

[Check for more details](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview)

Comment: you should add some ref link for better understanding.

Comment: please check this official link...
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview
i hope its useful ..@chintan

Comment: my mean is you should add this link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using multiple tags to define multiple checkboxes everytime you want one.
I once encountered this problem and I found a solution to this but I was defining the elements dynamically that is using the java code.

This **[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961777/android-linearlayout-horizontal-with-wrapping-children)** solved my query. **The given function in the page defines a way to create a new linear layout when the max width of the screen is reached for the particular device.**

I would also just like to advise **against using so much code** to define checkboxes in the xml file. This will result in increasing the size of the application. However if you could **define the names of the checkboxes in a string and then loop through them in the java code to create the checkboxes**, the apk file would be smaller and easier to download for the users.

I hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answers already given. We can add the ems to dimens 
like this in dimens.xml
3