# AutoResize and AutoRearrange TextView in Layout , View same as Chips in "Android L" Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-custom-view, android-5.0-lollipop

May be this question already asked by another member but i won't found any answer for my question.

My question is How can i resize and rearrange textview according to text.
Please take a look at image
[image]

This kind of view used in Gmail app for sender email id and in "Android L" its known as "Chips" [android Chips](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/chips-tokens.html)

Here i want to display 3 textview into sliding menu.
these 3 textview are inside relative layout.
Idea is if 1st textview text is long ("Swift" textview is something like "microsoft office" than "objective c " textview will be displayed below 1st textview "Microsoft office" and if first and second can share 1st line space than it will be displayed one after another.)

I tried AutoResizeTextView but it only resize font and it set textview height according to width so it not look good in terms of UI.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: this is not single textview it may be custom or multiple textview if this android activity than you can get view hierarchy from DDMS

Comment: @andruboy yes i know its not single textview..please read my question, In my question i mention about 3 textview..and I know we can get it by some custom view but million dollar question is how?

Comment: It is similar to chips from android L http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/chips-tokens.html (or at least the way they are viewed). Also, gmail app has something similar. Maybe AOSP would help?

Comment: @Swap-IOS-Android here is a nasty (but I assume working solution) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961777/android-linearlayout-horizontal-with-wrapping-children. Add children dynamically, track their size and if child to be added wont fit, add new line (or control its position differently) and place below.

Comment: @dominik4142 i found this https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one very good Library called FlowLayout which take care of everything..
[FlowLayout link](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)

Into my Relative layout

```
<com.test.FlowLayout
        android:id="@+id/chips_box_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start"
         >
```

```
chipsBoxLayout = (FlowLayout)keyword_layout.findViewById(R.id.chips_box_layout);
        FlowLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("Java");
        arrayList.add("Objective c");
        arrayList.add("Swift");
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
          TextView t = new TextView(context);
          t.setLayoutParams(params);
          t.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          t.setText(arrayList.get(i));
          t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
          t.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
          chipsBoxLayout.addView(t);
        }
```

and it works, Thank you @dominik4142 to give me hint about chips.

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://github.com/RanaRanvijaySingh/AdjustableLayout . What i did is create a new layout that extends linear layout and overridden **addView()** and **removeView()** function. This layout will allow you to add your own **View (Layout)** in horizontal orientation. The view keeps on adding until it exceeds the width you have defined for the layout, then view is automatically added to next line.

**The view in red is custom layout with Imageview - Textview - Imageview**

[image]