# ViewGroup that wrap its children with line breaking if there is no space in the current line

Tags: android, android-viewgroup

I have tried old solutions here:
[Line-breaking widget layout for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android?lq=1)

Is there a new proper way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) library by Google do this.

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:alignContent="stretch" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```