# Android gap text

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

i'm looking to implement a gap text / cloze in android.
Something like this:

> Usually, elephants weigh ___ tons, which makes them one of heaviest
>   mammals on earth after blue _______ (marine animals).

As long as everything is in one line, that's not to difficult to implement:
A horizontal linear layout of multiple TextViews/EditTexts will work perfectly fine.

However, this approach reaches its limit with sentences/paragraphs so long that they span multiple lines. "Hardcoding" new lines isn't a solution either, as i'm targeting different screen sizes. Any simple ways to fix that?

My solution in the moment is using a vertical linear layout, but this results in wasted space & ugly (much to long) editTexts:

> Usually, elephants weigh
>
> ________________________________________.
>
> tons, which makes them one of heaviest mammals
>
> on earth after blue
>
> _________________________________________.
>
> (marine animals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I tried a horizontal linear layout, where the children were both TextView and EditText widgets.  However, as you've probably noticed, they don't wrap around.

If you don't mind external libraries, a possible solution is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38190723/4979500

I haven't tried it, but it claims to be able to do a horizontal layout with wrap around.