# Android Layout - Text Too Wide?

Tags: android, layout

I have a `View` comprised of two `TextView` if first is too wide can I get the second to display on the next line?

Is there a solution?

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:text="If this text is too wide"
android:textSize="20px"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:id="@+id/del01"
android:paddingTop="3px"
android:paddingBottom="3px"
android:gravity="left"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:text="I want this on a different line"
android:id="@+id/del02"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is it a must to have two TextView's? Why not to use one and limit it to two lines?

Comment: I would assume it's because of how he wants the wrapping to behave; if it was a single TextView then it would wrap at the limit, but he wants it to wrap on each portion of the text.

Comment: Excellent question. I have been trying for some minutes and couldn't do it :(

Comment: I suspect the answer would be quite complex.  There was an old question on SO about wrapping layout that you might have to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android

Comment: Got it!!!! have two views v2a and v2b v1.measure(v1.getWidth(),v1.getHeight()); v2a.measure(v2a.getWidth(),v2a.getHeight()); if (lv.getWidth()< (v1.getMeasuredWidth()+v2a.getMeasuredWidth())) //too big v2a.setVisibility(View.GONE); else v2b.setVisibility(View.GONE); thanks for the thoughts anyway Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own view class derived from View and display both texts in that view. Override draw() and you can do whatever you want there depending on the sizes of the text.

Note: It is usually not a good idea to define sizes and paddings in "px". You should rather use "dp" which will be automatically scale on different screen sizes and densities.

Comment: Got it!!!!
have two views v2a and v2b
v1.measure(v1.getWidth(),v1.getHeight());
v2a.measure(v2a.getWidth(),v2a.getHeight());
if (lv.getWidth()< (v1.getMeasuredWidth()+v2a.getMeasuredWidth()))
    //too big
    v2a.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else
    v2b.setVisibility(View.GONE);

thanks for the thoughts anyway
Steve