# Related to android TextView

Tags: android, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android :Text Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386449/android-text-animation)

I want to know how I can implement the floating of the text in the textview of the android??

in my xml I have linear layout and inside it a textView

Thanks for Answer
in advance

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Do you mean "floating" ?..and what do you actually mean by that ?

Comment: I think he want to move text from left to right in textview, like news updates..

Comment: what the floating is? do you some time from your busy schedule to clear question.three comment has been post.and you did not respond to even one.Are seriously solve your problem

Comment: maybe this :) is that what you looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627422/how-to-create-floating-textviews-in-android

Comment: Maybe he means the ticker/marquee functionality?

Comment: float also means something in the CSS context right? CSS experts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386449/android-text-animation) may be it help.... :)

what i inderstood from your question is that you want to move text in text view, and the above link has something like moving view.. please see if it can give you a direction to work upon

Comment: Yes I want a marquee label and i solved it using string which contains html