# Reflowable mix of TextViews and EditTexts?

Tags: android, forms, layout, user-interface, reflow

I am trying to make a sentence-filling like interface, where I can have `TextView`s and `EditText`s mixed arbitrarily in a paragraph.

I have had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android), but the problem was that when I have [ `TextView1`, `EditText`, `TextView2` ] and the content of `TextView1` consumes 1 full line and 1 fifth of the second line, then `TextView1` will have to span the entire width because it is a rectangle. This pushes `EditText` to the next line, which is ugly.

So is it possible to create such kind of ViewGroup/Layout from existing stuff in Android, or I'd have to make a custom `View` from scratch?

In case I'm too bad at explaining, this screenshot describes my problem:

[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some work here :)

You should make two text views - one for line 1, one for line 2. Estimate the text, that fits on the first line, put it in the first text view. Put the rest in the second line, and it'll fit just nice.... I think you know this, and I doubt there is an easier way to do this :)

It's a nice task anyway.

Greets,
Danail