# Is there a widget (AbsListView) in Android that will show items in one row and if they don't fit put them below?

Tags: android, android-layout

what I want is like a gridView where every item could have its own width. Like in html if you just add a lot of span items inside a div block, the div will just grow as necessary to fit them.

Is there something already built for this purpose or should I try and create my own AbsListView implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such widget in Android.

Note that you would only extend `AbsListView` if you wanted individual items in the widget to be selectable. If you simply want a "flow layout", you would extend `ViewGroup` and create your own custom layout manager. There might already be an implementation of a "flow layout" available somewhere -- people have asked about it for a long time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I guess I just did not know that I was looking for FlowLayout. Now I can see a lot of answers ;) Too bad anyway there is nothing build-in, as I guess this is a very common scenario.

Comment: @LocoMike: The reason you're seeing the term "flow layout" is that Swing had a container by that name that has the characteristics you seek.

Comment: I have seen some ViewGroup implementations that have not really satisfied me, so I guess I will try and make my own AbsListView class. I am sure it will also be a very good exercise. Thanks!

Comment: @LocoMike: If by "very good exercise" you mean "requires Excedrin in industrial quantities", then, yes, I suspect that it'll be a "very good exercise"... :-)

Comment: +1 for Excedrin. Extending AbsListView is nearly impossible for a developer not on the Android team.

Comment: Note also that `ListView`s let you use `CursorAdapter`s, multiple selections and so on. On the other hand you actually *can't* extend `AbsListView` currently. So a custom `ViewGroup` is really the only way to go. (Actually you can copy all of `AbsListView` out of Android but apparently there are lots of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this question was answered here: [Line-breaking widget layout for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android)

I am using the RowLayout class (second answer), and it does the job very well.