# TextView and EditText cut off in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view, textview

I have a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation in which I add some TextView and EditText dynamically. My problem is when the TextView is long, it is cut off (by height) and the EditText is invisible.

[image]

[image]

Adding padding to the views didn't solve it. When setting the LinearLayout minHeight value, the TextView is displayed correctly but the EditText is still invisible.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></LinearLayout>
```

---

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

for (int i = 0; i < cntCount; i++) {
    TextView cntView = new TextView(getActivity());
    cntView.setLayoutParams(params);
    cntView.setText(cnt.get(i));

    contentContentView.addView(cntView);

    EditText answerView = new EditText(getActivity());
    answerView.setLayoutParams(params);
    answerView.setId(i);
    answerView.setHint("......");

    contentContentView.addView(answerView);

}
```

**EDIT**

I have found the solution and created a library. For those interested you can download it [here](https://github.com/ismaeltoe/flowlayout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LinearLayout` has an orientation of "horizontal" - it will add the next view to the right of the current view. This means that if the `TextView` wraps (fills the parent) there is no room for any additional views in the `LinearLayout` that will be visible on the screen (they will be added to the right of the visible layout).

If you are trying to place an `EditText` in the same line with a series of `TextView`s, then you will need to create a custom `TextView` and layout. This requires doing measurements about the placement and size of the `EditText` that are not standard with Android.

This post may help: [How to overlay EditText on TextView just after the end of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421758/how-to-overlay-edittext-on-textview-just-after-the-end-of-text)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up layout_weights for the EditText and the TextView instead of using wrap_content for the layout_width. That would make sure that the EditText will always be shown.