# Place Views dynamically on a new line in layout for horizontal placement when they overflow container

Tags: android, android-layout, overflow, containers, alignment

I have a `MapView` where `Drawable` markers are placed with a limit set to 10. A `RadioButton` is created for each marker to enable individually selecting them for movement to another location on the map. They use the same `RadioGroup` for mutual exclusivity.
When five `RadioButtons` are placed horizontally I want to start a "new line" across the screen for five more `RadioButtons`.

To achieve this is it possible to use a new `RadioGroup` on the second line which somehow links to the first one? Or is there a property for layouts(`ViewGroup`) that forces `Views` on a new line when it "overflows" its container horizontally? In my experiments layouts force `Views` further to the right when the container has no space for it on the screen.
`CSS` has a nice solution to this by setting `"overflow:hidden"` to contain elements within its container and it would be nice with something similar here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you might want to try the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android/560958#560958). It worked quite well for a similar problem I had some time ago.

Comment: Cheers. I can try that. This also reminded me of TableLayout, which I also could try with two TableRows, and loop in 5 RadioButtons for each row.