# Adding Views like continuous text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I wonder if there is a library that enables adding Views aligned like continuous text.

For example, if there are 3 Views next to each other in the current "line" and the fourth is too wide, then it will be carried over to the next line automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I get your question, but check out GridLayout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: No sorry that is not what i ment. I want to add Views with different width. So some lines with two views, some with three, and so on

Comment: Then you probably need to create a custom layout, this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android