# Flow Layout in JAVA File

Tags: android

This is my Project XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/flowLayout"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- enter code here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

I need to access it in the **JAVA file** which should contain 3 sentences in 3 text views ...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private View layout;
@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById();

        //enter code here
    }
    private void findViewById() {

    View layout = findViewById(R.id.flowLayout);

        //enter code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand, what is the problem?

Comment: I need to give 3 sentences in 3 text view in JAVA file and not in XML .... using flow layout

Comment: how to give width and height of the text view in the corresponding JAVA file??

Comment: you need to create a LayoutParams object, see updated answer.

Comment: did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: I want to add 3 text view in java file which is coming from 2 text view in very first line and 3rd text view is coming from next line coming to front line not from last. so i want to add orientation is horizontal in xml file.  could u refer this follow link alsohttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android   to see images in 38 question.

Comment: yes, i got it then its useful for my project.

Comment: Ya ... As per ur instructions i gave 3 sentences in 3 correspondin text views but the third sentence is getting disappeared due to the resoution of the mobile. I need to display it in the new line. How to do that?? For example it should be like in the image in this link..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android

Comment: @Emil Adz : Answer Pls ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806706/android-flow-layout-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a TextView to your layout do this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.flowLayout); //depending on which layout is it.
```

Then, Create a TextView, set it text and add it to the layout:

```
TextView tvText = new TextView(this);
tvText.setText("your desired sentence");
layout.addView(tvText);
```

and do this for all 3 of your `TextViews`, for setting the height and width use LayoutParams (example):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 2, 0);
```

As you can see this is the way you set Mergins as well, in the end set those params to the `textView`:

```
tvText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```