# Android-Flow Layout in JAVA

Tags: android, flowlayout

I m giving 3 sentences in 3 text views in JAVA file in horizontal orientation but only 2 text view that is only 2 sentences are comin but the third sentence gets disappeared due to the resolution of the mobile. My query is how to get the third text view in a new line from the starting postion of the second line and not at the last.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private LinearLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 15, 10, 10);

    TextView tvTextsecond = new TextView(this);
    tvTextsecond.setText("Heywhatrudoingtoday");
    tvTextsecond.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tvTextsecond.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    tvTextsecond.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    //tvTextsecond.setSingleLine(true);
    layout.addView(tvTextsecond);

    TextView tvTextthird = new TextView(this);
    tvTextthird.setText("Haiitssundaytowork");
    tvTextthird.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tvTextthird.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    tvTextthird.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    //tvTextthird.setSingleLine(true);
    layout.addView(tvTextthird);

    TextView tvTextfourth = new TextView(this);
    tvTextfourth.setText("Owebullshitruuselessfellow");
    tvTextfourth.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tvTextfourth.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    tvTextfourth.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    //tvTextfourth.setSingleLine(true);
    layout.addView(tvTextfourth);

}

private void findViewById() {
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.flowLayout);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you don't see the third `TextView` is that your layout has a horizontal orientation and while the first two `TextView`s fit the screen size the third one is getting pushed outside.

To fix this issue you can do several steps:

**1.** change your layout orientation to vertical in the XML or the java file, and that way the `TextView` will appear one after the other vertically.

**2.** if you want to keep more then one `TextView` in a row, then you should still set you main layout orientation to vertical, but for each row of `TextView`'s create a new layout with horizontal orientation using code and added the `TextView` to this layout.

```
LinearLayout tvRow = new LinearLayout();
tvRow.addView(firstTextView);
tvRow.addView(secondTextView);
```

Finally add this layout to your main layout:

```
mailLayout.addView(tvRow);
```