# Checking child is going out of bound in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am dynamically adding children in LinearLayout horizontally. I am adding child on button click. But after adding some children, say 4, others children go out of screen as these are being added horizontally. How can I check that child is going beyond screen in LinearLayout, and I need to create new layout? Or what can I do with the LinearLayout so that when it goes out of screen, it wraps itself?

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `LinearLayout` inside `HorizontalScrollView`, it will do all the necessary work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**EDIT** if you want your views to be wrapped inside the parent view, please take a look here [Line-breaking widget layout for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android/560958#560958)

Comment: It has created scrolling horizontally but I want that when space is filled horizontally, add child to the next row and so on. Can this be achieved? Thanks