# floating button does not show in view Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a feature where on click a button, new view/Button gets added from left to right, when it runs out of space it automatically adds the button to the next line.
Just following up this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android), after integrating I am unable to see the buttons in my view.

Any clue is appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_filter"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

   </LinearLayout>

     <com.mypackage.predicatebuttonclass
        android:id="@+id/predicate_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_filter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding text view dynamically

```
   predicateLayout myLayout;
         myLayout;= (PredicateLayout)mFilterLayout.findViewById(R.id.predicate_layout);


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
              {
                TextView t = new TextView(ProductListingFragment.this.getActivity());
                t.setText("Hello");
                t.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                t.setSingleLine(true);


                myLayout.addView(t, new PredicateLayout.LayoutParams(2, 0));
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the height of added view to 0 with this line:

```
new PredicateLayout.LayoutParams(2, 0)
```

So you can't see it! Because a view with 0 width **or** height property will not rendered.

Comment: thanks for response. found flowLayout open source library that was helpful as well.