# android LinearLayout with multiple rows

Tags: android, layout, view, android-gridlayout

In my app I added multiple views to a Horizontal Linear Layout from code. My problem is when number of views increased their not visible in single row and goes further the screen. Is there any layout that I can add views to it dynamically and if following view does not fit in first row, it placed in second row. At first I don't know the number of views though I want everything dynamic. 
something like this:
[image]

Comment: I don't think something like that exists, that I know of. Can't you just add up the widths of the children and if it is greater than the width of the parent, create a new horizontal LinearLayout and add them to that instead?

Comment: @billynomates I want to know is there a library written for this purpose or a simpler way of doing this. You know getting width of views before adding them to a parent is tricky.

Comment: @MohamadGhafourian : plz take a look at here hope it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android/560958#560958

Comment: try googling for:  android flow layout

Comment: @pskink Thank you very much. Flow layout helps.

Answer (score 3):

use this layout

```
  package com.shashi.app.utils;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.shashi.app.R;

    public class FlowLayout extends ViewGroup {
        private int mHorizontalSpacing;
        private int mVerticalSpacing;
        private Paint mPaint;

        public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                    R.styleable.FlowLayout);
            try {
                mHorizontalSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                        R.styleable.FlowLayout_horizontalSpacing, 0);
                mVerticalSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                        R.styleable.FlowLayout_verticalSpacing, 0);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }

            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
                    - getPaddingRight();
            int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);

            boolean growHeight = widthMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;

            int width = 0;
            int height = getPaddingTop();

            int currentWidth = getPaddingLeft();
            int currentHeight = 0;

            boolean breakLine = false;
            boolean newLine = false;
            int spacing = 0;

            final int count = getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

                LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                spacing = mHorizontalSpacing;
                if (lp.horizontalSpacing >= 0) {
                    spacing = lp.horizontalSpacing;
                }

                if (growHeight
                        && (breakLine || currentWidth + child.getMeasuredWidth() > widthSize)) {
                    height += currentHeight + mVerticalSpacing;
                    currentHeight = 0;
                    width = Math.max(width, currentWidth - spacing);
                    currentWidth = getPaddingLeft();
                    newLine = true;
                } else {
                    newLine = false;
                }

                lp.x = currentWidth;
                lp.y = height;

                currentWidth += child.getMeasuredWidth() + spacing;
                currentHeight = Math.max(currentHeight, child.getMeasuredHeight());

                breakLine = lp.breakLine;
            }

            if (!newLine) {
                height += currentHeight;
                width = Math.max(width, currentWidth - spacing);
            }

            width += getPaddingRight();
            height += getPaddingBottom();

            setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(width, widthMeasureSpec),
                    resolveSize(height, heightMeasureSpec));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            final int count = getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                child.layout(lp.x, lp.y, lp.x + child.getMeasuredWidth(), lp.y
                        + child.getMeasuredHeight());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
            boolean more = super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            if (lp.horizontalSpacing > 0) {
                float x = child.getRight();
                float y = child.getTop() + child.getHeight() / 2.0f;
                canvas.drawLine(x, y - 4.0f, x, y + 4.0f, mPaint);
                canvas.drawLine(x, y, x + lp.horizontalSpacing, y, mPaint);
                canvas.drawLine(x + lp.horizontalSpacing, y - 4.0f, x
                        + lp.horizontalSpacing, y + 4.0f, mPaint);
            }
            if (lp.breakLine) {
                float x = child.getRight();
                float y = child.getTop() + child.getHeight() / 2.0f;
                canvas.drawLine(x, y, x, y + 6.0f, mPaint);
                canvas.drawLine(x, y + 6.0f, x + 6.0f, y + 6.0f, mPaint);
            }
            return more;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
            return p instanceof LayoutParams;
        }

        @Override
        protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
            return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }

        @Override
        public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
            return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
        }

        @Override
        protected LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
            return new LayoutParams(p.width, p.height);
        }

        public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams {
            int x;
            int y;

            public int horizontalSpacing;
            public boolean breakLine;

            public LayoutParams(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
                TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                        R.styleable.FlowLayout_LayoutParams);
                try {
                    horizontalSpacing = a
                            .getDimensionPixelSize(
                                    R.styleable.FlowLayout_LayoutParams_layout_horizontalSpacing,
                                    -1);
                    breakLine = a.getBoolean(
                            R.styleable.FlowLayout_LayoutParams_layout_breakLine,
                            false);
                } finally {
                    a.recycle();
                }
            }

            public LayoutParams(int w, int h) {
                super(w, h);
            }
        }
    }
```

xml usage

```
 <com.shashi.app.utils.FlowLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            app:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            app:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
your views here
 </com.shashi.app.utils.FlowLayout>
```