# Android layout custom

Tags: android, android-layout

Please help me construct item for `ListView`. Each item of `ListView` contains line with `TextView` and `EditText`.

[image: expected]

So, it could also contain multiple sentences displayed in multiple lines of text. And sentence can contain several editText. On screen, layout must multiline switch auto (line break).

How I can make that?

I using predicate layout from here [Line-breaking widget layout for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android)

But I have problem with baseline on predicate layout:

[image: baseline problem]

xml item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/matcher_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.***.customviews.EditableTextView
        android:id="@+id/editable_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

public class EditableTextView extends PredicateLayout {

    protected LTTXT1Item item;

    public EditableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void init(LTTXT1Item item) {
        this.item = item;
        removeAllViews();

        if (item.isValidItem()) {
            String[] text = item.getTextWithoutSeparators().split(LTTXT1Item.EDIT_TEXT_PLACE);

            for (String str : text) {
                final TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
                textView.setText(str);
                addView(textView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                final EditText editText = new EditText(getContext());
                editText.setHint("?");
                addView(editText, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), item.toString() + " is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your layout xml

Comment: @Clairvoyant body of questions has been changed.