# Layout where objects are moved to the next line

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, view, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical LinearLayout and I add there TextViews programmatically. I need to realize the behavior when if for example the fifth element of my vertical LiunearLyout doesn't fit on the screen it goes to the next line. The example is bellow.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line-breaking widget layout for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549451/line-breaking-widget-layout-for-android)